How to save several figures from an animation created by FuncAnimation?
is it possible to save, for instance, 10 figures from a video, that is created as follows?
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=num_frames, interval=40, blit=True)  # Interval is in milliseconds

dpi = 300  # Adjust this value as needed
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=60, bitrate=5000)
ani.save('animation_Hradec.mp4', writer=writer, dpi=dpi)

Is there an argument of FuncAnimation for this? Thank you very much

This previous answer may be of interest.
